# How to add an HTML form element dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a text field to a form dynamically using javascript. From what I can tell, my code should work.

```
function change()
{
textField = document.createElement("text");
textField.id="sub"+count;
textField.name="sub"+count;
textField.value="Enter a name for another new subcategory";
textField.size="35";
textField.onchange="javascript:change()";
textField.onFocus="javascript:clearField()";
document.getElementById("addCatForm").appendChild(textField);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
var field = document.createElement('input');
field.type = 'text';
```

NB if you're doing lots of Javascript development, you might want to use a framework, such as [ExtJS](http://sencha.com/products/extjs)

The code to do it would be:

```
var field = Ext.get('form').createChild({
    tag: 'input'
    //other options
});
field.on('change', change);
field.on('focus', focus);
```

Comment: You may want to use "setAttribute" so `field.setAttribute("type", "text")`.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a TEXT element, but adding things to it for an INPUT element.